# Laravel - Database not updating on save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I checked all the fields in the object and they are being changed fine. The function completes without errors and the Session::flash gets changed but the save is not updating the database. Any help would be great.

```
public function confirmLeague($id, $authToken)
{
    $league = League::find($id);

    if ($league == null || $league->AuthToken != $authToken || $league->Validated)
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'The league does not exist.');
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $league->Validated = true;
    $league->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'The league has been added.');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Table script:

```
        Schema::create('leagues', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('Id');
        $table->string('LeagueName', 250);
        $table->string('City', 50);
        $table->string('Province', 50);
        $table->string('Sport', 50);
        $table->string('Type', 10);
        $table->string('Website')->nullable();
        $table->string('Person', 100);
        $table->string('Phone', 20);
        $table->string('Email', 100);
        $table->string('Description', 250)->default('');
        $table->boolean('Validated')->default(FALSE);
    });
```

Comment: what are your getting on flash, when redirect finishes? error or success?

Comment: Did you try with `validated` (lowercase)? Just guessing.

Comment: the flash is showing success. It is executing but just not doing anything. Also i tried both upper and lowercase (stored as uppercase in the database)

Comment: Are you sure your database datatype is equal to a boolean and not a TinyInt or string or something?

Comment: From my understanding, tinyint and boolean are the same. Even when I tried saving as 1 it failed

Comment: plz share table structure here

Comment: do you have created_at and updated_at colomns in table ?

Comment: I think Rakesh is onto something.  I've had errors when trying to save models because I forgot to either set timestamps to false in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue. Turns out laravel doesn't like capital letters in the column names in the database. I just renamed all my columns to lowercase and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Query Builder rather than Eloquent, this code directly update your data in the database :) This is a sample:

```
DB::table('post')
            ->where('id', 3)
            ->update(['title' => "Updated Title"]);
```

You can check the documentation here for more information:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#updates